# How to check the value and retrieve it from database if it exists using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

It's a simple question, but I'm new to Hibernate and working in Hibernate 4.2.7. Here is my scenario.

I have a list of product codes so I'm looping through the values like:

```
Vector<productslist> p = prodcts.getlists();
int size = p.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    productslist pl = p.elementAt(i) 
    p.setProductcode(pl.getProductcode());
    p.setProductName(pl.getProductName()); 
    session.save(p);
}
```

Before inserting into database I need to check if the productcode exists in the database. If not I can insert the values, if it exists I need to return back the productID for that productcode.

**productID is auto-generated by database.**

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: Vector!! you really need Vector?

Comment: @TheEwook That! That's what you notice as the big problem here?

Comment: **Unrelated notes**. 1) You seem to have errors in your code: `p.setProductcode()`, `p.setProductName()`. "p" is a *Vector* in your code, so of course there are no such methods there. 2) Related to your `productslist` class: class names in Java by convention should be upper [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_case) (a.k.a. PascalCase). Read more in [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Of course not! but I'm always astonished of seeing people posting code that doesn't even compile. So if the op didn't want to bother doing this simple check, why should I ;) +1 for your answer btw!

Comment: @TheEwook  - I apologizes for error code here. What i thought was its just an idea for question, so it doesn't matter for answer. But you guys expect with runnable code.Then i will correct it my mistake and going forward will post compile code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) to do this; try something like `"from products where lower(productcode) = " + productCode`. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) are some tutorials on HQL.